# dynamically changing list construction

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website in which I need a dynamically changing list based on User's inputs (like searches or drop-down selects). One example is of list of courses in [Coursera's website](https://www.coursera.org/courses?orderby=upcoming). Also, how is each course shown in a block with its picture, name etc.? I searched a lot but couldn't get help because I don't know what's it called exactly. I went through Coursera's page source but its entire JavaScript and I couldn't get any helpful HTML or CSS.

Any ideas to get me started with will be very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

**Start learning `jQuery` and `javascript`**

It is the most simple task in jquery..

For starting help learn about the [**html()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp) of jQuery or [**innerHtml()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) of JavaScript either of them can help u achieve this task

If you want my suggestion working in jQuery is much simpler as easy so Best Luck

=================================================================

**Edit** --->

Here is a simple Demo for you to understand this dynamic data adding

though i have used [**.append()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp) to the following task

In the demo i am populating more `<li>`'s to the `<ul>` using the `append()` when a user event occurs(here i have button click but they can be so many more)

Here is a [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/qMf2X/) for you to understand hope it helps.

Comment: @tigerden check the edit hope it helps